# Switch Bits, but does not switch them back?

Tags: c, bit, switching

I was messing around with a bit of code and decided to attempt to switch some bits around in files, and then switch them back to get the original file. Somehow, it changes the bits, but will not change them back.

Here is what I have:

The magic happens by me opening a file and fread into rByte[0] and rByte[1].

```
unsigned char rByte[] = {0, 0};

int isBitSet(unsigned char byte, int bytePosition){

    unsigned char mask[] = {128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};
    return ( (byte & mask[bytePosition]) != 0 );
}

unsigned char setBit(unsigned char byte, int pos) {
    byte |= (0x01 << pos);
    return byte;
}

unsigned char clearBit(unsigned char byte, int pos){
    byte &= ~(0x01 << pos);
    return byte;
}

/* DO NOT TOUCH */

void switchBits (unsigned char byte1, unsigned char byte2, int x, int y) {

    int reg1 = 0;
    int reg2 = 0;

    reg1 = isBitSet(byte1, x);
    reg2 = isBitSet(byte2, y);

    if ( (reg1 == reg2) ) {

    }

    if ( (reg1 == 0) && (reg2 != 0) ){
        rByte[0] = setBit(byte1, x);
        rByte[1] = clearBit(byte2, y);
    }

    if( (reg2 == 0) && (reg1 != 0) ){
        rByte[0] = clearBit(byte1, x);
        rByte[1] = setBit(byte2, y);
    }

}
```

Now, I assume that if the same `switchBits()` will be applied, the way I perceive it, the program should go back to regular. I made a music file make weird noises, but did not go back to normal.

Comment: If bit's could be more than 1, you switch like this: 0 1 2 3 ( original ) -> 1 0 3 2 ( switched ) ?

Comment: switchBits(rByte [0], rByte[1], 4,5); should switch the fourth and fifth bit of thr two bytes

Comment: Maybe you should use else if, instead of a lot of if's. Because if a change is made, no changes need to be made anymore.

Comment: if (condition) { 

} else if(condition) { 

}
else { 

}

Comment: Yeah but no matter what, only one will be executed because they could either both be true or one has to be false

Comment: You are indexing bits differently in `setBit` and in `isBitSet`. `isBitSet(setBit(0, 2), 2)` will return false.

Comment: Your program has lots of vulnerability bugs related to signedness of integers and implicit type promotion. You need to study _integer promotion_ and _the usual arithmetic conversions_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `rByte` is globally defined (which is not nice).

You have the position of your bits reversed in `isBitSet()` compared to `setBit()` and `clearBit()`.

Example assuming `pos = 0`

`isBitSet` checks the MSB (most significant bit) as `mask[0] == 128`
but in `setBit` and `clearBit` functions you shift `0x01 << 0` meaning it corresponds to a `1`.

edit:
What I suggest is that you change

```
unsigned char mask[] = {128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};
```

to

```
unsigned char mask[] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128};
```

edit end

You should overthink your design of the function, just chaining `if`s seems quite strange and the logic you want to implement could be improved. Here an example with simplified logic, you might do it another way to be more specific on the logic, so just see this as a suggestion.

```
if ( (reg1 == reg2) ) {

}
else{
  if ( (reg1 == 0)){
    rByte[0] = setBit(byte1, x);
    rByte[1] = clearBit(byte2, y);
  }

  else{
    rByte[0] = clearBit(byte1, x);
    rByte[1] = setBit(byte2, y);
  }
}
```

Another thing which would simplify the program again would be a switch function that just makes a `0` out of a `1` and vice versa. This is easily done by the XORoperator `^`. Meaning if both are different you just have to switch the state of both bits so it would reduce your function to this.

```
if ( (reg1 != reg2) ) {
  rByte[0] = switchBit(byte1,x);
  rByte[1] = switchBit(byte2,y);
}
```

Comment: It is globally defined, but what I'm asking is why would it not work if I switchBits () twice. Like why would I not get original bytes. I assume because that ordee?

Comment: And if so would you be able to give me an example in code?

Comment: I told you the reason. It is because you look for different bits in isBitSet() then you modify in your functions below